# Message box pop up

Tags: vba, excel, message

I need to build a code to give me a pop up message if the value of a cell (Price) is bigger than another cell (Target). 
**If PRICE > TARGET then pop up a window** (ideally with sound).

Also if **I hit ok** i need to **register "true"** to another cell or if i hit **cancel** insert to a cell **FALSE**

My FIRST vba code so please show some understanding, Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sub userinput()

Dim ireply As Integer

If Range("C6").Value > Range("E6").Value Then

ireply = MsgBox(prompt:="Price" & Range("F6").Value & " Reached target. Stop tracking ?", Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="Tracking")

If ireply = vbYes Then

Range("B6").Value = "TRUE"

ElseIf ireply = vbNo Then

Range("B6").Value = "FALSE"

End Ifs

If Range("C7").Value > Range("E7") Then

End If

If Range("C8").Value > Range("E8") Then

End If

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: you have `End Ifs` and this is `End If`

Comment: your `If Range("C7").Value > Range("E7") Then
    End If` does absolutly nothing, because you're closing the `if ` statement instead of closing your first `if`

Comment: @Hearner : I think that the reference of row 7 and 8 are to show that it want this to work on each row, see answer in few secs! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make this possible directly when you input data into Excel, you'll need to place this into the sheet module of the sheet that you want it to work on :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim iReply As Integer

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Application.Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
Else
    If Range("C" & Target.Row).Value > Range("E" & Target.Row).Value Then
        Beep
        iReply = MsgBox("Price" & Range("F" & Target.Row).Value & " Reached target. Stop tracking ?", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Tracking")
        If iReply <> vbCancel Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = "TRUE"
        Else
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = "FALSE"
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy replies.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Calculate worksheet

Application.Calculate

Dim ireply As Integer
' Perform the test

If Range("C7").Value > Range("E7").Value Then

' Ask me if Excel needs to keep tracking and assign YES or No

ireply = MsgBox(prompt:="Security " & Range("F7").Value & " Reached target. Stop tracking ?", Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="Tracking")

Beep

End If

If ireply = vbYes Then

Range("B7").Value = "TRUE"

ElseIf ireply = vbNo Then

Range("B7").Value = "FALSE"

End If

Comment: What is that code for? Did mine solved your problem? (did you see where to place it?)